# Yii framework CMultifileupload submit not working

Tags: php, yii

I want to upload multiple images and save the image name to database table. There are two attributes in the table - `id` and `image_name`. In form, I use `CMultifileupload` widget to upload number of images. When I submit the form, there is no effect. Then I try to echo something underneath of `if (isset($_POST['ImageTemp'])) {` but no effect. So I am on hold to see the output whether multiple image upload or not. However, I wrote as:

in form:

```
<div class="form form-custom">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'image-temp-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions'=>array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ),
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image_name'); ?>
    <?php
    $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'image_name',
        //'name' => 'files',
        'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
        'denied'=>'File is not allowed',
        'max'=>3, // max 10 files
    ));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'image_name'); ?>
</div>



<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

in controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model=new ImageTemp;

    $type = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : 'post';

    if (isset($_POST['ImageTemp'])) {

        echo "something but no output";

        $model->attributes = $_POST['ImageTemp'];
        $photos = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image_name');

        // proceed if the images have been set
        if (isset($photos) && count($photos) > 0) {

            // go through each uploaded image
            foreach ($photos as $image => $pic) {
                echo $pic->name.'<br />';
                if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/project'.$pic->name)) {
                    // add it to the main model now
                    $model->image_name = $pic->name; //it might be $img_add->name for you, filename is just what I chose to call it in my model
                    $model->save(); // DONE
                }
                else{
                    echo 'Cannot upload!';
                }
            }
        }

    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and in model, I have written the rule:

```
public function rules()
{

    return array(
        array('image_name', 'file','types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, image_name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

I am trying based on [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/567/multiple-files-uploader-with-cmultifileupload/) but do not understand where I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILES['ImageTemp']` is your friend ;)

So in your controller you should do

```
if (isset($_FILES['ImageTemp'])) { 
   // do something..
}
```